# Load Admob ads before an activity is loaded, so that they appear instantly instead of after 3-5 seconds?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, admob, ads

The way my app is designed, I load ads on the main menu, a "ending" page, and a hopefully (if I can get this resolved) on a page that pops up for 5 seconds before it continues automatically to another.

Specifically for the automatically loaded page that closes after 5 seconds, is there a way that I can load the ad in the background, and have it instantly available for when I change activities? If I just have the normal code in there, it usually doesn't have enough time to load before it continues.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of showing an Ads on a page that pops up for only 5 seconds?  Most of the revenue comes from clicks and on such a short time, don't expect any click excerpt maybe some accidental.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried tackling this problem on BREW handsets but they are far less capable and there was no way I could realistically solve this problem. Our solution was to show a HTML browser as a screen in our application, and while it didn't load 100% of the time for all attempts it still was able to generate a fair amount of revenue.

I haven't tried this on Android.

Can you create a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) ahead of time, fetch the AdMob ad as if it were embedded in a webpage, and reveal the page inside the WebView? This is instead of using the AdMob SDK.